# Check if there are missing dates in a certain time range

Tags: dataframe

Following dataset:

```
 Name   Year   more columns
 A      2000
 A      2001
 A      2002
 A      2003
 B      2000
 B      2001
 B      2003
 C      2001
 C      2002
 ....

library(data.table)
DT = rbind(use.names = FALSE, 
  data.table(Name = "A", Year = (y <- 2000:2003)), 
  data.table("B", y[-3]), 
  data.table("C", y[-c(1,4)]))
```

I want to get the all values from my column name that have at least one missing year between 2000-2003.
So in this example, I want to get the following values from my column name.
B because 2002 is missing and C because 2000 is missing.
I want to check if there are any years between 2000-2003 missing for all my values in my column Name.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just check the number of rows in each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way using base R:

```
aggregate(Year ~ Name, df, FUN = function(x) all(2000:2003 %in% x))

  Name  Year
1    A  TRUE
2    B FALSE
3    C FALSE
```

Comment: Don't think it any more complicated using `data.table`, e.g, `DT[, all(2000:2003 %in% Year), by = Name]` (if OP already has a data.table)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use an anti-join against a cross join of all possible combinations:

```
library(data.table)
DT[, CJ(Name = Name, Year = Year, unique = TRUE)][!DT, on = .(Name, Year)]
```

> ```
>    Name Year
> 1:    B 2002
> 2:    C 2000
> 3:    C 2003
> ```

This will show the missing items.

Comment: To avoid typing colnames multiple times ... `DT[, do.call(CJ, c(.SD, .(unique = TRUE)))[!.SD, on=names(.SD)], .SDcols=c("Name", "Year")]`